# Не могу запустить бота в дискорде

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я написал простой код для бота, вставил токен, добавил бота на сервер он в оффлайне разумеется.
Я захожу в консоль и пишу: python bot.py . и ничего не происходит.[image: командная строка]

```python
import discord

class MyClient(discord.client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))


client = MyClient()
client.run('В оригинале тут токен')
```

Comment: Внимательнее читайте документацию, даже в вашем случае я вижу расхождение в коде https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [доки](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client), посмотрите как оформляется код.

Приведенный ниже будет работать, можете сравнить с ним :)

```
import discord
 
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(client.user))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
    
client.run('В оригинале тут токен')
```

Если принципиально работать через `class`, то в скобках нужно указать `discord.Client`